Handle custom URL schemes in a Windows Java application
I'm trying to handle custom URLs like "myapp://foo" in a Java app. I added the registry entry and when typing such an URL into a browser, it asks if I want to open it with said app which then launches and gets the full URL as an argument. So far so good.
The problem is that I only get the URL when it launches. If the app is already running, I want it to react to that. Instead the app is launched again.
I tried using setOpenUriHandler() of the Desktop class but it seems this is not supported on Windows and I'm also currently bound on using Java 8, while this has been added in Java 9.
As I also did this for the OS X version of the app, I used Thomas Tempelmann's answer
here. Using the Java code at the end and Eclipses SWT library, it's working as intended.
I was hoping something similar might be possible for Windows since there is a Windows version of the SWT library available. Unfortunately, I don't really understand much of the code or how Thomas even got the native names and addresses.
So my question is: How do I achieve that a running app is reacting to custom URLs and Windows not trying to start the app again? Either with eclipses SWT library or other solutions I have not yet found.

Everything in Thomas Tempelmann's answer is macOS only. It uses SWT internal methods which are completely different on each OS.
